# Declare class insider class in CSS

Tags: css

Although I found some examples on the web, but it didn't solve my issue. Hope someone can help me. 
I have two css files. One is reset all style attributes. There is the code (snippet)

```
html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
}
```

I cannot modified the reset.css because of the rule. I only work on the style.css. There is what I did to make the HeaderStyle works. I created a new class and it works.

```
tr.dgrdHeaderfntsize13e td
{
   font-size: 1.4em; /* 1.3em 11px */
   font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #F2F7FA;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: none;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: left;

}
```

My question is how to create the class for the fontsize on cell. I tried `td.fntsize13e` and `tr td.fntsize13e` doesn’t work. There is my .aspx page

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgrdLawyers" Runat="server" DataKeyField="GlobalID" GridLines="Both"     
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"    CssClass="dgrdInnerBorders noOuterBorder talgnC"  
      CellPadding="5" >
   <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" Position="Top" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
      <%--<HeaderStyle CssClass="dgrdHeader  talgnL fntsize13e"></HeaderStyle>--%>
           <HeaderStyle CssClass="dgrdHeaderfntsize13e"></HeaderStyle> 
         <ItemStyle CssClass="dgrdItem talgnL fntsize13e"></ItemStyle>
```

Comment: Can you show the *rendered* HTML, and not the ASP source?

Comment: Can you show the < head > of your document ?

Comment: Dumb question but is `fntsize13e` declared anywhere?

Comment: fntsize13e is declared. There is my HTML:

Comment: <table class="dgrdInnerBorders noOuterBorder talgnC" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" id="dgrdLawyers" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

<tr class="dgrdItem talgnL fntsize13e">
  <td class="talgnC">3</td><td>Gary Users</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>G.W Users</td><td>18Dec2012</td>

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your rendered html is correct and does not have inline styles being set like..

```
<td style="font-size:20px;">asdf</td>
```

and in your css you can use !important to force a property value

```
td.fntsize13e {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

That should work and will force the font size but I'd try and avoid that. Figure out where the font size is really being set and fix it there.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I also checked that it doesn't has inline style for fontsize.

Comment: Can you provide the rendered markup? That will help us a lot :)

Comment: Just realized that the font-size may not work unless you have the doctype set to standards. like...<!doctyp html>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you scope your CSS.  Try

```
#dgrdLawyers . . .
```

And use !important as a last resort if you have inline styles like @teewuane suggests.

Comment: I know it works, but I want to not to have id because there are a lot of datagrid with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You should clarify your question and maybe show the rendered markup.  A upvote would be nice for others who don't understand scoping.